# Move X number of rows in a table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to move X number of rows down in a table using jQuery...

I can do the following and it works....

```
/* Now let's move next 3 times to arrive at the foo account */
for (var rowCount = 1; rowCount <=3; rowCount++) {
    foobarRow = $(foobarRow).next('tr');
}
```

I realize I could go

```
    foobarRow = $(foobarRow).next('tr');
    foobarRow = $(foobarRow).next('tr');
    foobarRow = $(foobarRow).next('tr');
```

also...

but I'm wondering if there's not a more jQueryish way to accomplish the same thing?

like, I don't know, but(totally made up jQuery syntax follows)...

```
foobarRow = $(foobarRow).next('tr').number(3);
```

Comment: if foobarRow is a JQuery wrapper for a TR why the initial $(fooBarRow)?  If its not you are changing the type of foobarRow which is not a good practice

Comment: fobarRow is a wrapper for a table row...I'm sorry but I don't understand your question( if foobarRow is a JQuery wrapper for a TR why the initial $(fooBarRow)?) ...maybe I should go nextFoobarRow = $(fooBarRow).next('tr') ?

Comment: OK sometimes you have just walk away from it for a while...I see what you're saying...I should just go $(foobarRow).next('tr'); no need for the  foobarRow = $(foobarRow).next('tr'); stuff....Thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can match elements by their index [`:eq(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/).

`$("tr:eq(2)")` selects the third `<tr>`. Note, this is a zero-based index.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```js
foobarRow = $(foobarRow).siblings().get(2);
```

Comment: Anthony,
Thanks for your answer...
This gets me the row I want...
lineItemsRow = $(lineItemsRow).parent().children("tr").eq($(lineItemsRow)[0].rowIndex + 3)
The two answers are so close(and correct and a big help) that I'm gonna take Jonathan's answer just because he was first...Thanks again, Greg