# How to move a <tr> up or down within <table> via jQuery?

Tags: jquery

What's the elegant way to do this?

Comment: Maybe this link would help you a bit:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444801/move-x-number-of-rows-in-a-table-using-jquery

Answer (score 7):

Here's a quick plugin I wrote for you.
Call it on a table, and give it the the old row and the new row position.

```
$.fn.extend({ 
  moveRow: function(oldPosition, newPosition) { 
    return this.each(function(){ 
      var row = $(this).find('tr').eq(oldPosition).remove(); 
      $(this).find('tr').eq(newPosition).before(row); 
    }); 
   } 
 }); 

$('#myTable').moveRow(4, 3);
```

Here's an example on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/uroyi

Comment: +1 - very succinct answer. If the `<tr>` has event handlers bound to it, will this plugin preserve them?

Comment: Sorry but it won't. According to the jQuery documentation you will need to do an appendTo directly to preserve the event handlers.
http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/remove#expr

Comment: I removed my comment above since i was wrong, here's the info I still stand by. Thanks bang, for calling me out.

The events will not be saved. I would suggest using $.live() as it would be more efficient for any more than 3+ rows. In the case of live, the events aren't attached directly to the element anyways, so it would work with less-friendly plugin.

Comment: you could also `clone(true)` the row before removing it and then insert the clone.

Comment: A note for jQuery 1.4.x+ - instead of the `remove` you can use a `detach` and it will keep the events.

Comment: It doesn't work for me when switching the 2nd last row and the last one. use John McMillion update instead

Answer (score 4):

Alex's answer works great, but found one issue, if you move something to the very end of the list, it can't insert it.  Here's a slightly tweaked version that fixes it...

```
$.fn.extend({
    moveRow: function (oldPosition, newPosition) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var row = $(this).find('tr').eq(oldPosition).detach();
            if (newPosition == $(this).find('tr').length) {
                $(this).find('tr').eq(newPosition - 1).after(row);
            }
            else {
                $(this).find('tr').eq(newPosition).before(row);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two javascript functions that will do the job:

```
    function MoveRowDown(tableId, index)
    {
        var rows = $("#" + tableId + " tr");

        rows.eq(index).insertAfter(rows.eq(index + 1));
    }

    function MoveRowUp(tableId, index)
    {           
        var rows = $("#" + tableId + " tr");

        rows.eq(index).insertBefore(rows.eq(index - 1));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move it to the top or bottom would be easier, though this would not help you :(

```
//lets say you want to avoid/skip table headers and use a tbody
var tbody = $('tbody','#table');
//now you want a specific row bring to top
$('tr.chieftan',tbody).prependTo(tbody);
```

To move from a specific index, to a specific one :

```
$('li:eq(2)').insertBefore($('li:eq(1)'));
```

Will move the 3rd child before the 2nd (the indexs are 0 based).

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**:

```
<table id="t1">
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>efg</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript (jQuery)**:

```
var row0 = $('#t1 tr:eq(0)');
$('#t1 tr:eq(1)').after(row0.contents());
row0.remove();
```

Answer (score -1):

I would assign IDs to all my `<tr>`s.