# How to know index of a <tr> inside a <table> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm now implementing something like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845600/how-to-move-a-tr-up-or-down-within-table-via-jquery) (specifically, the effect takes place when the row is clicked)

How do I know what the index of the row is inside the table?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you defined the click handler directly on the `tr` elements, you can use the `index` method like this:

```
$('#tableId tr').click(function () {
  var rowIndex = $('#tableId tr').index(this); //index relative to the #tableId rows
});
```

If the click event is bound not directly on the `tr` element (if you are using an anchor, a button, etc...), you should find the closest `tr` to get the right index:

```
$(selector).click(function () {
  var rowIndex = $('#tableId tr').index($(this).closest('tr'));

  return false;
});
```

Try an example [here](http://jsbin.com/ijuvu).

Comment: This won't work right if the page has multiple tables.   Probably best to look for sibling `<tr>` elements.

Comment: Shouldn't the selector of the $.index() call be restricted to the parent table of whatever TR was clicked, rather than a generic table tag?

Comment: @TM, @Jonathan: was a typo, restricted to a `#tableId` element

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('#tableId tr').click(function () {
    var index = $(this).siblings('tr').index(this);
});
```

You don't need `tr` in the call to `siblings` if you are sure your html will be well-formed.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question:

```
$("#id tr").click(function() {
  alert($("#id tr").index(this));
});
```

If you just do:

```
$("table tr").index(this);
```

and you have multiple tables on the page, you will get an erroneous result.

That being said, you don't need to know the index to move rows up and down in a table. For example:

```
<table id="foo">
<tr>
  <td><a href="#" class="up">Up</a> <a href="#" class="down">down</a></td>
  <td>First row</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><a href="#" class="up">Up</a> <a href="#" class="down">down</a></td>
  <td>Second row</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><a href="#" class="up">Up</a> <a href="#" class="down">down</a></td>
  <td>Third row</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

with something like:

```
$("a.up").click(function() {
  var row = $(this).closest("tr");
  if (row.prev().length > 0) {
    row.insertBefore(row.prev());
  }
  return false;
});
$("a.down").click(function() {
  var row = $(this).closest("tr");
  if (row.next().length > 0) {
    row.insertAfter(row.next());
  }
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [`HTMLTableRowElement.rowIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/rowIndex)?

> The `HTMLTableRowElement.rowIndex` read-only property represents the position of a row in relation to the whole `<table>`.

Beware that if you have `thead`, `tbody` or `tfoot` tags wrapping the rows, these will be counted as well.

```js
$("table tr").click(function () {
  console.log(this.rowIndex);
});
```