# How to move an <option> up down in a <select>?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858175/how-to-know-index-of-a-tr-inside-a-table-with-jquery/1858239#1858239) should clearly demonstrate how to move items up and down. It's done on tables but applies equally easily to lists and selects.